# Android studio, change button text with each click in java

Tags: java, android-studio, button, text, click

I tried something that works but could there be a better way to do it?

```
private Boolean set = false;

    public void btnClick(View view) {
        set = ! set;
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        if(set == true) {button.setText("Hi!");}
        else{button.setText("Hi again!");}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply do

```
 button.setText(set? "Hi" : "Hi again");
```

Answer (score 0):

The method has parameter as a View class. Which means you simply do not need to define the button.

```
private Boolean set = false;

public void btnClick(View view) {
    set = ! set;
    //Then the below line of code can be written somewhat like the above user mentioned. Changing a minor detail.
    view.setText(set ? "Hi" : "Hi again");
}
```

And you can mention this method in layout as button's `onClick` property.